# Complex conjugate of contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I have a closed-loop *counter-clockwise* contour integral over a function $f(z,t)$:

$$F(t)=\oint_C dz\enspace f(z,t)$$

Then suppose I want to know the complex conjugate of $F(t)$.  What happens to the contour itself?  does the contour flip orientation (*i.e.* become clockwise)?

Comment: Write out the integral as $\int_0^1 f(z(u),t)z'(u)\,du$, where $z(u)$ is a parametrization of the contour, then it's easy to take the complex conjugate.

Comment: This is true if $f(z,t)$ is holomorphic with respect to $z$, but otherwise I am not sure. Also I think you assume the circle is centered at origin.

Comment: That is the definition of a (complex) path integral. It doesn't matter if $f$ is holomorphic in $z$, and it doesn't matter what the path is so long as there is a differentiable map $[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ given by $z(t)$.